# Quorum: Generating Public Key for a Given Address

Tags: public-key, quorum

I stood up the [7nodes example](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum). There is a public key:

`ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc=`

provided for the `privateFor` field in order to change a contract value while keeping it private.

How was this value derived? Can it be done for other accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Quorum node's keypair is generated using Constellation. Depending on which version you have, you run either of the following to generate *tm.key* (private key) and *tm.pub* (public key) files. You can just hit return when prompted to set a password unless you really want one.

Old way:

```
constellation-enclave-keygen tm
```

New way:

```
constellation-node --generatekeys=tm
```

The public key is the one you need to use in the `privateFor` field.

If you are interested in exploring Quorum beyond 7-nodes, I have an example that spins up as many nodes as you request in separate Docker containers, and generates all of the enodes, keys, genesis file etc.  You can find it here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-docker-Nnodes

See the [exposition of the setup file](https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-docker-Nnodes/blob/master/Nnodes/README.md) for all the details about key generation, config files etc.

Comment: I see the .pub and .key files in the 7nodes/keys folder now. The commands above will come in handy for future accounts. Thanks. Btw, I like your demo. I built my 7nodes example in a docker container.